# Where should hooks go? Only in modules?

Tags: 7, hooks

I need to use 1 hook from webforms.  Where does this belong? Do I have to make a custom module just to implement 1 hook or is there a more appropriate place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom module is the most appropriate, probably only, place for your hook(s).

Most hooks only get run for modules; there are exceptions such as `hook_form_alter()`, `hook_theme()` etc. which are also called for themes, but generally speaking you'll need to write a custom module for any hooks you want to implement.

In case you're not familiar with building modules take a look at the [Module Developer's Guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules).